# Remaining logged into one GAE application after logging out of another GAE application

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We have a Google App Engine Java application (defined as App A) that provides information of a user's role based on the user logged in.  This is a corporate application, so it is required to set the Google Authentication to our domain.

In general, the link will be called by other GAE apps (defined as App B), so the users will never have to explicitly log into the app.  These other GAE apps will also have the Google Authentication set to our domain.

We are using the standard `UserService`

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

Assuming two users are using the same computer. The problem we are having is when user A logs out of App B, and user B subsequently logs on to App B, App A still thinks that user A is logged in, and so returns the role information of user A.  So now User B has the roles that he shouldn't have.

As I have read, the logged in user gets a `SACSID` cookie set for the appspot.  I have tried to invalidate a session, change the `SACSID` cookie so that it's empty. (as shown by code below).  I have tried to put the following code before the `UserService` calls, as well as also just before I return the response for the servlet.

```
Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    log.info("Cookie " + i + ": " + cookies[i].getName());
    if (cookies[i].getName().equals("ACSID")) {
      cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
      cookies[i].setValue("");
      cookies[i].setPath("/");
    }
    if (cookies[i].getName().equals("SACSID")) {
      cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
      cookies[i].setValue("");
      cookies[i].setPath("/");
    }
    res.addCookie(cookies[i]);
  }
}
```

This solution seems to work.  However, only on the second time I hit App A's link that the user credentials refresh.

Example: user A logs into App B.  user A hits the link for App A.  App A will return the roles for User A

User B logs into App B.  user B hits the link for App A.  App A returns the role for user A still.  user B hits the link for App A again, and only this time, App A will return the role for user B.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?